# I can't get text of a link element that's inside on hover dropdown

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I want to click on dropdown menu item that appears on hover, but it doesn't work. Here is a HTML of website I am testing:

```
    <div id="header-nav" class="skip-content">
    
<nav id="nav">
    <ol class="nav-primary">
        <li  class="level0 nav-1 first parent">
           <a href="http://demo-store.seleniumacademy.com/women.html" class="level0 has- 
                    children">
                          Women
           </a>
           <ul class="level0">
                 <li class="level1 view-all">
                        <a class="level1" href="http://demo- 
                                  store.seleniumacademy.com/women.html">
                                     View All Women
                        </a>
                 </li>
                 <li  class="level1 nav-1-1 first">
                        <a href="http://demo-store.seleniumacademy.com/women/new- 
                                 arrivals.html" class="level1 ">
                                     New Arrivals
                        </a>
                 </li>
            </ul>
         </li>

         <li  class="level0 nav-2 parent">
               <a href="http://demo-store.seleniumacademy.com/men.html" class="level0 has- 
                        children">
                               Men
               </a>
           <ul class="level0">
               <li class="level1 view-all">
                     <a class="level1" href="http://demo-store.seleniumacademy.com/men.html">
                               View All Men
                     </a>
               </li>
               <li  class="level1 nav-2-1 first">
                      <a href="http://demo-store.seleniumacademy.com/men/new-arrivals.html" 
                               class="level1 ">
                                New Arrivals
                      </a>
               </li>
               <li  class="level1 nav-2-2">
                      <a href="http://demo-store.seleniumacademy.com/men/shirts.html" 
                               class="level1 ">
                                    Shirts
                      </a>
               </li>
               <li  class="level1 nav-2-3">
                      <a href="http://demo-store.seleniumacademy.com/men/tees-knits-and- 
                               polos.html" class="level1 ">
                                  Tees, Knits and Polos
                      </a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>        
     </ol>
</nav>
```

I shortened code a bit, but it is all the same, just text inside  is different.

I made a method that i want to use so i can click on different items in nav bar menu. Here is code for the method:

```
public Subcategory openSubcategory (String subcategoryName){
        WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.nav-2"));
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.moveToElement(ele).perform();
        List<WebElement> subcategories = 
        driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a.level1"));
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        for (WebElement element: subcategories) {
            if (element.getText().equals(subcategoryName)) {
                element.click();
                break;
            }
        }
        return new Subcategory(driver);
    }
```

And here is how i use it in the test:

```
 @Test
    public void OpenMenShirts() {
        MainPage mainPage = new MainPage(driver);
        mainPage.openSubcategory("Shirts");
        Subcategory subcategory = new Subcategory(driver);
    }
```

I didn't add assert in the test because it won't even click on "Shirts" for example. Method find 26 elements, but it won't get inside IF block, probably becase all 26 elements are null. Method goes 26 times over List ---> for each ---> if ---> return new Subcategory, but don't go inside if block.

This is the website I'm using for test: http://demo-store.seleniumacademy.com/

And this is the link to download my project (ZIP) so you can check where i made mistake: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/d54a4592f07c54a58fa2e4f779fe007820220215134918/b9fd46

Answer (score 0):

First hover over the element you need to hover on (move the mouse on, but without any click):

```
 WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("<xpath>"));
    //Creating object of an Actions class
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    //Performing the mouse hover action on the target element.
    action.moveToElement(ele).perform();
```

Later wait around 1 seconds or less, and click the element:

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
// or wait even more
Thread.sleep(1500);
//Find the element you wish to click on:
// In this example find any A tag
// inside a li tag with class that contains 'level0'
WebElement myElm = driver.findElementByCSS
("li[class*='level0'] a");
// click:
myElm.click();
```

Comment: I canged code, you can see, it hover right element, but still no click. I added implicit wait because sleep wants me to add some throw